# Setting permission for a remote private message queue - MSMQ

Tags: .net, msmq

I'm using MSMQ to transfer data between geographically distributed systems. How can i configure the security of my message queue to give full access to a remote user. Also how can i do it through commands (not powershell)?

Thank you

NLV